# IIS rewrite URL rule - OR condition

Tags: regex, url, iis, url-rewriting

In IIS rewrite URL rules I try to catch all URL which start with `fr`  , `de` or `ru` .

For single expression it is  - 
`^fr(.*)$`

How to make it for multiple (`"fr" , "de" or "de"`) ?

I tried - `^(fr | de | ru)(.*)$` with no success  .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the spaces out of your expression:

```
^(fr|de|ru)(.*)$
```